# Why does it give Unable to merge dex for play-services-safetynet?

Tags: android, flutter

I added this in the build.gradle file: `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:12.0.1'`

Then it shows this error: `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.`

I'm using [f_grecaptcha](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/f_grecaptcha) and followed the documentation but still got this error.
Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Try cleaning the project after adding library. I think it will work, it happens some times with me after upgrading to android studio 3.0. and make sure the internet is fine

Comment: You don't have to add the `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:12.0.1'` to the build.gradle since it's already there in the lib, but a lower version, and it's probably safer to use the version they have specified in the lib. Not sure that is the cause but you could try removing the one you have provided and try again.

Comment: finally, it works, I remove the part in the build.gradle and it work.